# What is the recommended approach and python library for downloading files from a website that requires a checkmark before downloading?

Tags: python, web-scraping, automation

every 1st of the month, I'm required to go to an internal company website, log in with my credentials, then navigate to the directory (Inbound > Archive) that contains the daily transactions in text format and download them to my desktop. To download the file, I have to manually put a check mark next to the file that I want to download and scroll all the way to the bottom of the page to click on the "download" button. I do this approximately 90 times (30 days for 3 regions) every month and I'd like to automate this process if possible. I've successfully followed the following tutorial to build a web scraping for IMDB, but I don't think i can apply the same methodology to download my daily transaction files. is this a process that can be automated with python and if so what are the recommended approach/libraries for executing this? thanks in advance!

https://www.dataquest.io/blog/web-scraping-beautifulsoup/

[my code so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RPkOz.png)

Comment: you should read about `selenium`

Comment: thanks, I will check it out.